# Is it possible for a platform to have "partial" IEEE754 floating point types

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer

I'm wondering, is it theoretically possible for a platform to implement the IEEE754 specification for a `double`, but not for a `float`? (And the converse case.)

Comment: A compliant complier need not implement IEEE754, so certainly a compliant compiler could employ it for one FP type and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here is a real world example of the opposite thing:

Take a look at this slide about CUDA numeric from the [following presentation.](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/floatingpointwebinarjune2011.pdf)

[image]